# return only the first two terms of custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, terms, limit

hey im trying to figure out how i can display only two terms that are associated with a custom post type. I tried using `$wpdb` but that doesn't work for me since i need the term links as well. any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help. First, get all the post's terms; then, cycle through them with a `foreach` loop to retrieve and echo each one's link. The last line of code will limit the cycle to the first two terms.

```
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(); // If you're not in the loop, you should pass the post's ID as an argument.

    $i = 0;

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $name = $term->name;
        $href = get_term_link( $term->term_id ); 

        echo '<a href="' . $href . '">' . $name . '</a>';

        if ( ++$i == 2 ) break; // Limit to first 2 tags

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that using this default function

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
     'order'             => 'ASC',
     'hide_empty'        => true, 
     'exclude'           => array(), 
     'exclude_tree'      => array(), 
     'include'           => array(),
     'number'            => '', 
     'fields'            => 'all', 
     'slug'              => '',
     'parent'            => '',
     'hierarchical'      => true, 
     'child_of'          => 0,
     'childless'         => false,
     'get'               => '', 
     'name__like'        => '',
     'description__like' => '',
     'pad_counts'        => false, 
     'offset'            => '', 
     'search'            => '', 
     'cache_domain'      => 'core'
 ); 
 $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```

More details on this link:
https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Function_Reference/get_terms